# Vertex/Edge removal from isomorphic graphs

Tags: graph-theory, group-isomorphism, graph-isomorphism

Given two isomorphic graphs $G$ and $G'$ that are undirected and weighted (or unweighted), does there exist a **canonical sequence of edge removals** from the graphs, such that the subgraphs at every step of the sequence remain **isomorphic** to one another? In other words, a removal of edges (possibly random or not) strategy that is invariant to isomorphism.

Comment: Of course, impose a canonical edge labeling and then remove the edges in order. (see the notes on the nauty software package for details about canonical labelings)

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thanks for your reply. Actually, the problem is that I have a set of graphs, out of which some of them could be isomorphic to one another. Now, I need a "rule" of edge removals, whereby two isomorphic graphs will remain isomorphic after applying this rule. What you are suggesting works if I first canonically label all graphs, and then "remember" the order in which I removed edges? Initially, I was going with a random retention of edges, so dropping edges with probability p every time, but this is clearly not useful for isomorphic graphs.

Comment: @MorganRodgers is it possible to maybe choose a "representative member" from each isomorphism class in the set of graphs? Or is that a very expensive process?

Comment: That is essentially what a canonical labelling would do, it would label both of your graphs in a unique way as a particular representative of their isomorphism class in the set of graphs, so that their labelings will match.

Comment: But there are algorithms to do this that are much more efficient than calculating the isomorphism class and choosing a representative.

Comment: If you canonically label all graphs, the edges will be numbered, and then you just remove them 1, 2, 3, ... so no remembering needed. Canonical labeling will also let you know which are isomorphic (at the start) because they will then be identical after labeling (it will be faster than pairwise testing isomorphism).